# Qt: MainWindow->show() crashes program on call

Tags: c++, qt

I've been working on this program using Qt in c++ and so far so good. However I then needed to get this program moved to another machine. I have subversion, so I committed every file in the project folder and checked it out on the new machine. After jumping through some hoops to get it to successfully build and running, I get this error:

```
 ASSERT: "dst.depth() == 32" in file qgl.cpp,.
 invalid parameter passed to c runtime function qt
```

I tried stepping through the program to find the point where it crashes and found that it was after everything had been initialized and show() is called for the class that inherits the QMainWindow class. The *c->showView()* line calls QMianWindow->show().

```
 ----------main.cpp------------
 #include <QApplication>

 #include "ModelI.h"
 #include "ControllerI.h"
 #include "Model.h"
 #include "Controller.h"


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
      QApplication a(argc, argv);
      ModelI *m = new Model();
      ControllerI *c = new Controller(m);
      c->showView();                         <- ERROR HERE
      return a.exec();
 }
```

The confusing part of the problem is that the program works perfectly fine on my machine when show() is called. I don't know what could be different between the two machines to make the program behave so differently. Both use the same version of Qt (SDK 2010.05). Both are developing with Eclipse. The only difference I can find is that my compiler is MinGW 4.5.0 and the other machine's is MinGW 4.5.2.

**EDIT 1:**

This is what Controller::showView() looks like.

```
 void Controller::showView()
 {
     mView->show();
 }
```

And this is how mView is initialized.

```
 mView = new View(mModel, this);
```

Comment: And what does `Controller::showView` do?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg`void Controller::showView()
    {
     mView->show();
    }`  Where mView is an object of the class that inherits show() from QMainWindow.

Comment: And what is `mView`? Is it a valid pointer? How do you initialize it?

Comment: mView is definitely a valid pointer. Nothing would work if it wasn't. And I know that the program runs until show() is called.

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly initialized mView and didn't write something like "QWidget* mView = new QWidget()" ?

Comment: Yes, mView is being correctly initialized.

Comment: run the program with valgrind and look if it doesn't complain about anything.

Comment: Have you tried `make clean distclean` then run qmake again?

Comment: I think I may have done something like this, but I'll give it a try.  @hyde

Comment: Tried this out with no luck. @hyde

Comment: Well, that assert seems to come from OpenGL class, and suggests something (display? Some image?) is not in 32 bit color mode. I'd check the line in Qt sources...